# Python - Reading and print between lines ?

Tags: python

I have this code where I'm reading from a plain text

python file:

```
from itertools import islice

def phones():
    with open('phones.txt','r+') as f:
        lines = islice(f, 2, 4) #lines 2 and 4 only
        for line in f:
            found_phone = line.find('Phone')
            if found_phone != -1:
                Phones = line[found_phone+len('Phone:'):]
                print Phones 
    return Phones

phones()
```

My problem is I want to print the word next to "Phone" between lines 2 and 4,
it's printing every word after "phone" I want only between lines 2 and 4.

This is my text file

```
First lines of Phones
        Phone Blackberry #Line 2
        Phone iPhone     #Line 3 
        Phone Huawei     #Line 4
Second lines of Phones
        Phone Samsung
        Phone LG
```

This is my output:

[image]

What I want to print only is between lines 2 and 4
I would like this output:

```
Blackberry
iPhone
Huawei
```

I was trying to do it with `itertools` but it's not working...
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `for line in f` looks at every line in the file. I think `for line in lines` might be what you want to do.

Comment: You could also use `startwith` https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith, so you don't need to splice + find.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here. Firstly, you specify `lines` as your slice, but then loop over the whole file, `f`. Secondly, your slice won't return what you're after - `islice` appears to be zero-based  and won't include the upper limit (from my tests in Python 2.7) and so the section you're actually after is `islice(f, 1, 4)`.

The code with these corrections is as follows:

```
from itertools import islice

def phones():
    with open('phones.txt','r+') as f:
        lines = islice(f, 1, 4)
        for line in lines:
            found_phone = line.find('Phone')
            if found_phone != -1:
                Phones = line[found_phone+len('Phone:'):]
                print Phones 
    return Phones

phones()
```

This returns

```
Blackberry

iPhone

Huawei
```

To remove the lines between the values, you can use `print Phones.rstrip()` rather than `print Phones`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
lines = [line.split() for line in open('phones.txt','r+')]
lines = lines [1:4]

select = [x[1] for x in lines ]
```

output => ['Blackberry', 'iPhone', 'Huawei']